# Scrollview is overlapping above elements when scrolled in xamarin android project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
`<ContentPage>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
    <Control>   //top menu
        <StackLayout>
          <Grid>    // 2rows
           <Label>  //row 0
             <StackLayout>  //row 1
            <ScrollView>
               <Grid>   //4rows
                <AccordionView>
                    <AccordionItemView #1/> //row 0
                    <AccordionItemView #2/> //row 1
                    <AccordionItemView #3/> //row 2
                    <AccordionItemView #4/> //row 3
                </AccordionView>
               </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
             </StackLayout>
          </Grid>
        <StackLayout>
    <Control>   //bottom menu
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>`
```

Xamarin.forms version(4.3.0.947036)
We are still facing issues in our scrollview, when scrolled, the elements above the scroll are overlapped.
Even our top elements are absolute and at fixed position.
So in our case the scrollview is set in the middle of our page where we have top and bottom menus and it should scroll only in its intended scrollview area.
We have tried various solutions and renderers but we are still stuck.
Most popular solution `IsClippedToBound = "true"` also does not work.
This issue is observed only in android our ios works just fine and perfect.

Comment: Please post your xaml

Comment: Please provide us with your UI code and/or an image of the issue itself.

Comment: @MihailDuchev I have updated my code structure of xaml page.

Comment: You could firstly update the version of XF to the latest (4.6.x) . If the issue still exists, you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .